# Numerically solving a PDE in Matlab: Eikonal in an exponential formulation and initial/boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, markov-chains, matlab, queueing-theory

I am currently working on a small research project as a part of my degree. The project is centered around Continuous-time Markov Chains, and based on this paper :

https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-03102188/

Currently, I should verify if a proposed analytical solution to the following equation, a version of the Eikonal equation, agrees with the numerical one, by numerically solving the following on Matlab, and comparing it with the analytical solution:

$$e^{d\phi(x,y)\over dy}- (y+1)e^{-d\phi(x,y)\over dx}-1=0$$
I have found the following initial and boundary conditions:
$$ \phi(0,0)=0$$
$${d\phi(0,0)\over dy}=log(1+e^{d\phi(0,0)\over dx})$$

I am not super well versed in PDE's, and much less so in Matlab. I have the following questions:

1. Would you say the conditions I have found contain enough information? I am not sure if I have everything I need to solve this?
2. The Matlab guide for solving PDE's wants the coefficients in a very specific form. How would I go about reformulating this so that Matlab will work for me? How would I address the exponential outer functions of the partial derivatives?

Comment: You will need at least a few more things to pose the problem well: 1) What is the domain of the PDE? 2) You will need a boundary condition on all boundaries of the domain. For example, if your domain is the unit square, you would need BCs on each side. Right now you only have two conditions at the same point. 3) You will have to put the PDE in a better form. The first two steps would probably be to add 1 to both sides and then take the natural log of both sides.

Comment: Although, you should note that if $y$ takes values less than minus one, you can't take the log of both sides and it would be up to you to figure something else out. Nothing's comes to mind immediately for me.

Comment: Thanks, I see! I have that both x and y are positive reals in a closed interval, so that takes care of the domain and the log. Now I need to find a boundary condition for the other side, right?

Comment: Almost. If you have $y\in [c,d]$ and $x\in [a,b]$ then you need to take all four boundaries into consideration: 1) $y=c$, with $x$ free. 2) $y=d$ with $x$ free. 3) $x=a$ with $y$ free. Finally $x=b$ with $y$ free.

Comment: Hm. I just noticed that your PDE is first order. that changes matters. I'm less familiar with this type of problem. I would honestly try a basic finite difference scheme starting at the axes. I would guess a boundary condition on each of the $x$- and $y$-axes could work.